# match regex with value contaning in object type

Tags: java

I have one situation

Where I'm reading a whole file content as a object type so that I could match the whole file data pattern with my regex.

So what I 'm doing right now..I'm converting that object type to string and storing whole file data into variable of string type. But i guess that would not be good approach because if file comes with lot of data there could be a memory issue.

So is there any way I could match that info storing into object type variable with my regex ?

because when I'm trying to match `object.matches(regex)`....its throwing error .

Right now am doing like this

Input file component: That will read a file as a object type

Then after that I'm storing that object info into string context variable like this. And then matching with my regex. So in this code only if any I could do enhancement to avoid memory issue.

```
context.variable (of string type) = object.toString;
context.variable.matches(regex);
```

Any suggestion please.

Thanks !!

Comment: Try reading the error message.

Comment: @SLaks please check this..here is the error  http://prnt.sc/dc468l

Comment: Please include your full code and error as text in the question.

Comment: That's all what I have in my etl java code. But explained more. Maybe now you could suggest me ..!!

Comment: If your goal is to avoid memory issue, you can read the file throught a loop, like a webserver does. 1000kb match? Yes > out. No? Read next 1000kb and add them. Match? Yes > Out. No? Remove the first readed 1k kb, move the last readed sequence in your buffer beginning, read the next 1k kb, match, again and again. It can be usefull to know what you are looking for (mime type?)

Comment: but how it would achieve my result to match whole file pattern with my regex...looping will go layer by layer. Is there any now way to match object type info to my regex ? I cannot break my file info..that whole needs to matched with my regex at once only.

Comment: @SLaks   It looks like this ....http://prnt.sc/ddaw30

Comment: No, you can't match an object with a regexp. If you provide more details about what you want to achieve we can maybe help.

Comment: @Henry...so is there any way I could store this object.toString() in hash variable and then compare with regexp..Then clear the cache !!